# Error when compiling with custom Framework

Tags: xcode, cocoa, frameworks, dyld, install-name-tool

I try to compile my app with an external Framework. When I execute it, I get the following message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/iLifeAssetManagement.framework/Versions/A/iLifeAssetManagement
  Referenced from: /Users/laurent/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReadPhotoStream-gdhuayfwgpajuxcwdognnhfqmnzt/Build/Products/Debug/ReadPhotoStream.app/Contents/MacOS/ReadPhotoStream
  Reason: image not found
```

The framework was added in the Build Phase, and I even tried to execute

```
install_name_tool -id @rpath/iLifeAssetManagement.framework/Versions/A/iLifeAssetManagement <folder_to>/iLifeAssetManagement.framework/iLifeAssetManagement
```

Any idea what I could still be missing ? Thanks.

Comment: Is this framework being bundled with your `.app`?

Comment: It appears on the left side, and the Target membership is clicked for the right app. Now, how to check if it is effectively bundled ?

Comment: If you are building your app and framework from within the same Xcode Workspace (sensible) then you will need to invoke a post-build script to copy the framework into `app-bundle/Contents/Frameworks` and run `install_name_tool` on the executable to load the `.dylib` from `@executable_path/../Frameworks/YourFramework.dylib`.